# How to search LDAP by user name and domain

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have the AD Global Catalog configured. There are several domains in catalog. How can I query all users from one of subdomains?

I have tried such query buy nothing found

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com)(sAMAccountName=Administrator))
```

How can I fix this query to make it working?

Comment: can you try with the below query : (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=Domain Users,cn=Users,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com)(sAMAccountName=Administrator))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the users from one of the subdomains in AD Global Catalog :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=Domain Users,cn=Users,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com)(sAMAccountName=Administrator)
```

**Reference** : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx